# Android sqlite cursor - out of memory

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, out-of-memory

I am trying to debug an 'out of memory' error that I am experiencing, so to condense my example for the purpose of reaching out for help, I have a button, when clicked it queries the db and returns all the values into an ArrayList, the ArrayList is then used to populate a RecyclerView.  This is successful, however if I press the button a second time, the 'out of memory' error occurs.  The query returns a very large amount of data, and from the log I can see that with just 1 press of the button, not much memory is available (running on an emulator).  I came to that conclusion from this line in the log:

`com.wizzkidd.myapp D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1459K, 2% free 91444K/93016K, paused 40ms, total 40ms`

and, as previously explained, the second press of the button gives this error:

`com.wizzkidd.myapp E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 152-byte allocation.`

The error is pointing to my database helper class, more specifically, this section of code:

```
public List<MyInfo> getAllFromDb() {
    List<MyInfo> myArrayList= new ArrayList<MyInfo>();   
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MyInfo myInfo = new MyInfo();                                      
                myInfo.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                myInfo.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));
                myArrayList.add(myInfo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to get data from database");
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return tvGuideInfoList;
}
```

I have researched previous articles here on SO and the majority of answers say that the cursor must be closed in the finally block.  But as you can see above, I am already doing this.

Comment: How many records you have got in myTable?

Comment: How many records are in `myTable`?  Do they contain blobs?  Also, `myArrayList.add(MyInfo);` is erroneous (your adding the class, not the `myInfo` object).

Comment: @pathfinderelite I made a type, I have edited my post.

Comment: myTable contains just string and integer values, no objects.  There are in excess of 93k rows returned from the query.

Comment: If the first query is using all of memory, you can expect the second query to run out if you are still holding any references to the data returned by the first query...

Comment: @antlersoft how do I go about purging the memory in preparation for the query to be executed again?

Comment: @WizzKid - Not sure because it is in another part of program, but most likely you need to clear out your RecyclerView

Comment: I'm trying to use @antlersoft 's suggestion as I believe this is the correct route to take, or at least try, however I am unsure how to clear the RecyclerView correctly because my RecyclerView is populated in an AsyncTask background thread.

Therefore I would think that I need to clear the arrayList, and notify the change in data set within the onPreExecute.  I am trying the following but to no avail:

`arrData.clear(); //clear list`
`myInfoViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@antlersoft pointed me in the right direction, because I needed to clear/empty the data in my adapter that was used to fill my RecyclerView.

I came up with this quick method which allowed me to create a blank ArrayList, for MyViewAdapter which I then use it for the RecyclerView.  I believe by filling the adapter with a blank ArrayList, it forced the Garbage Collection to clean up the previous data, thus allowing me to have a fresh pool of memory ready for the next fill.

```
private void clearRecyclerView() {
        myViewAdapter = new MyViewAdapter(activity, new ArrayList());
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myViewAdapter);
        myViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```